# CSS in Safari, applied only after closing Inspector/editing 'live'

Tags: css

I've tried the empty style tag trick but still no go.

Opening: sharpsma.com inside of the latest Safari, the far bottom right promo copy over the Sharp Zenigata promo is pulled over left.

Open the Dev tools in Safari and then just closing, snaps it into place. Or, any editing.

All works in all other browsers from IE7+, FF, Chrome and Safari 5 but in Safari 6, it seems to be getting hung.

Visiting the site in Safari 6 will be the easiest way to see the issue. Then, just open and close the dev tools and the promo copy snaps into place.

Any ideas on what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have few errors in html code (* marked with stars, open site in Firefox, view source, and you will get better picture), in that part of page:

```
 <div id="ThreePanelPromoContainer">
                  <div class="promoBoxContainer">
                     <a href="/sharpledlcd"><img src="sites/all/themes/sharptwentythirteen/images/front-page-bttm-all-led-promo.png" alt="lcds"/>
                       <p class="promoBoxTeaser">Sharp offers an extensive line of Industrial Strength LCDs.<br />
                        <span class="learnMore">Learn More **>></a><**/span></p>
                  </div>

                  <div class="promoBoxContainer promoBoxesMiddle">
                     <a href="http://www.sharpmemorylcd.com/" target="_blank"><img src="sites/all/themes/sharptwentythirteen/images/front-page-bttm-memory-lcd-promo.png" alt="lcds"/>
                       <p class="promoBoxTeaser">Memory in every pixel allows for rich content on a small display.<br />
                        <span class="learnMore">Learn More >**></a><**/span></p>
                  </div>  

                  <div class="promoBoxContainer">
                     <a href="http://www.sharpleds.com/" target="_blank"><img src="sites/all/themes/sharptwentythirteen/images/front-page-bttm-zenigata-promo.png" alt="zenigata"/>
                       <p class="zenigataFrontPromo">Because life happens in full spectrum.<br />
                        <span class="learnMoreZenigataPromo">Learn More **>></a**></span></p>
              </div>
```

i guess that Safari is more sensitive to these errors than other browsers. :)

Comment: Thanks. I tried the HTML &#817 entity then used &gt; for those symbols. Cleaned up the nesting and removed all html errors (save for one onClick that doesn't affect this ) it works, but every 2 or so refreshes and it doesn't. Very weird. I had bad nesting (p inside of an a) and I thought that was the real culprit but nope!.

Comment: Hm... @kellyjohnson don't ask my why, but this fix is working: <p class="zenigataFrontPromo" style="
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    left:210px;
    width: 137px;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);

">  so rather use left:, than right... there is too much css, can't figure out why, lol :)

Comment: hmm, I'll try it. I've set the class the same as the other and that works. Seems having a 'right:xx' is the cause. But, I'll try that rgb color...ps, yes on css. Drupal is fun.

Comment: no, color shouldn't be issue, i just copied it from FF developer toolbar... :)

Comment: ok, good idea to keep left. That seems to be working. Will mark the answer, thanks!